# v4l2loopback on gcp cannot depmod / compile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, debian, v4l2loopback

i'm trying to make fake webcam using v4l2loopback on a docker container inside gcp instance.

i'm using `debian:stretch` with `4.9.0-9-amd64` kernel

so far, these are steps that i tried to compile the v4l2loopback:

- `apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to install proper header
- `apt-get install kmod` and `apt-get install make` so i can use `make` and `depmod` feature
- `apt-get install aufs-dkms aufs-tools aufs-dev` to get the `modules.builtin.bin` file

after steps above, i cloned the v4l2loopback repo, run `make && sudo make install` command, and finally `depmod -a` command. But when i run `depmod -a`, i got this warning:

```
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/4.9.0-9-amd64/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /lib/modules/4.9.0-9-amd64/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

when i check it manually, there are no `modules.order` and `modules.builtin` inside the `/lib/modules/4.9.0-9-amd64` directory.

so when i tried to load the v4l2loopback module using `modprobe v4l2loopback`, it gives me error like this:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.9.0-9-amd64/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Operation not permitted
```

how can i fix this? or how can i compile the `v4l2loopback` properly on my environment?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I realized that it is only possible to load the module via `insmod` command instead of `modprobe` and you would be ready to use. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20070/whats-the-difference-between-insmod-and-modprobe) you can find an explanation about the differences between these methods.

Example: `sudo insmod PATH/TO/THE/FILE/v4l2loopback.ko devices=2 card_label="camera1","camera2" exclusive_caps=1,1`